# Strange C++11 mutex behavior

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

I am trying to implement a counting semaphore using binary ones.

The code logic is well known and it has been tested before using Qt's `QMutex` class and it is known to work properly (tested with a producer-consumer multithreaded driver).
I have tried manual control of the `l` mutex (to lock the class), `lock_guard` and `unique_lock` objects, to no effect.

A thread calling `acquire()` seems to get blocked on the `block` mutex (not consistently though), even when other threads call `block.unlock()`. The only way to make the code work is to replace the `block.lock()` line with `while(block.try_lock());` Then everything works properly.

The code works if I replace the `block` mutex with a condition variable.

```
#include <mutex>

class semaphore
{
private:
    int value=0;
    std::mutex l, block;

public:
    semaphore(int i=0);
    semaphore(const semaphore&)=delete;
    semaphore(const semaphore&&)=delete;
    semaphore & operator=(const semaphore&)=delete;
    semaphore & operator=(const semaphore&&)=delete;
    void acquire();
    void acquire(unsigned int i);
    void release(unsigned int i=1);
    int available();
    bool try_acquire(unsigned int i=1);
};

//---------------------------------
semaphore::semaphore(int i)
{
    value=i;
    block.lock(); // make sure that any thread trying to lock will block
}
//---------------------------------
void semaphore::acquire()
{
    l.lock();
    value--;  

    if(value <0)
     {
        l.unlock();  // release the semaphore while waiting
        while( block.try_lock());  // LINES IN QUESTION 
        //block.lock();            // LINES IN QUESTION 
     }
     else
         l.unlock();
}
//---------------------------------
void semaphore::acquire(unsigned int i)
{ 
    while(i--)
        this->acquire();
}
//---------------------------------
void semaphore::release(unsigned int i)
{
  l.lock();
  while(i--)
    {
      value++;  
      if(value <=0)
        block.unlock();
    }
  l.unlock();  
}
//---------------------------------
int semaphore::available()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(l);
    return value;
}
//---------------------------------
bool semaphore::try_acquire(unsigned int i)
{
    l.lock();
    bool res=false;
    if(value>=(int)i)
    {
        value-=i;
        res=true;
    }
    l.unlock();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: don't ever call `lock` or `unlock` manually. Instead use [`std::lock_guard` and friends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) otherwise you're risking deadlock if you leave scope early for some reason.

Comment: Note: A _mutex_ is not a binary semaphore. If you have a binary semaphore (or a counting semaphore) then you can use it like a mutex, but the reverse is not true. A binary semaphore can be used in ways that a mutex can not. StaceyGirl's answer (below) describes some things that you can do with a binary semaphore that you can not do with a mutex.

Comment: Thank you all. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behaviors:

- `try_lock` cannot be called by a thread that already owns the mutex, otherwise, the behavior is undefined. Line `while( block.try_lock());` is incorrect.
- `unlock` can only be called by a thread that owns the mutex, otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

The #2 is also wrong for [`QtMutex`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html#unlock). If the code was "working", it did so by an accident.

You need a proper semaphore implementation, something that is partially covered [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/340284/mutex-vs-semaphore-how-to-implement-them-not-in-terms-of-the-other/362533#362533).